# Masking a field in React without using plugins

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, masking

I need to mask the SSN  field as 123-45-6789 in React,

My aim is to do that without using plugings like react-input-mask,input-mask etc.

```
My input 123456789
Expected input 123-45-6789
```

Can we do that? By regex or something without plugings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use regular expressions to do it during the onChange event like this:

```
_onInputChange = (event) => {
    var string = event.target.value;
    string = string.replace(/-/g, "");
    var regex = /^([^\s]{3})([^\s]{2})([^\s]{4})$/g;
    var match = regex.exec(string);
    if (match) {
      match.shift();
      string = match.join("-")
    }
    this.setState({ssn: string});
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/98924/)

However this will only mask the value after the whole number is typed out.